# Can you compare two SPSS datasets if if the cases are out of order?

Tags: spss

My goal is to check to see if Database A contains the same information as Database B. However, the cases do not match. Is there a way to check this?
For example, Database A contains the ID number 625 located at case number 5, but Database B has the same ID but is located at case number 80. How would I match these values?

Comment: You can sort the tables by ID so the order matches (look up `sort cases`), and you can match the tables together so the same IDs are aligned and you can do the comparison through calculation - look up `match files`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Data menu, the Compare Datasets option allows this, by specifying your ID variable.
For more, you may check [the official IBM SPSS documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/26.0.0?topic=files-comparing-datasets)